# why I get huge number in converting V-reresentation to H-representation in sage?

Tags: sage, simplex, polyhedra

I have a set of vertices and I want to find a H-representation of them. I used sage to do that but I got weird number in the inequalities!
 here is my code:

```
vert2 = [[1,2,3,4,2,3,6,0,0,7,6,8,0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,4,3,2,3,4,1,0,3,0,1],[1,1,2,3,4,2,3,6,0,0,7,6,8,0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,4,3,2,3,4,1,0,3,0],[0,1,1,2,3,4,2,3,6,0,0,7,6,8,0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,4,3,2,3,4,1,0,3],[3,0,1,1,2,3,4,2,3,6,0,0,7,6,8,0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,4,3,2,3,4,1,0],[0,3,0,1,1,2,3,4,2,3,6,0,0,7,6,8,0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,4,3,2,3,4,1],[1,0,3,0,1,1,2,3,4,2,3,6,0,0,7,6,8,0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,4,3,2,3,4],[4,1,0,3,0,1,1,2,3,4,2,3,6,0,0,7,6,8,0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,4,3,2,3],[3,4,1,0,3,0,1,1,2,3,4,2,3,6,0,0,7,6,8,0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,4,3,2],[2,3,4,1,0,3,0,1,1,2,3,4,2,3,6,0,0,7,6,8,0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,4,3],[3,2,3,4,1,0,3,0,1,1,2,3,4,2,3,6,0,0,7,6,8,0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,4],
[4,3,2,3,4,1,0,3,0,1,1,2,3,4,2,3,6,0,0,7,6,8,0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7],[7,4,3,2,3,4,1,0,3,0,1,1,2,3,4,2,3,6,0,0,7,6,8,0,1,2,3,4,5,6],[6,7,4,3,2,3,4,1,0,3,0,1,1,2,3,4,2,3,6,0,0,7,6,8,0,1,2,3,4,5],[5,6,7,4,3,2,3,4,1,0,3,0,1,1,2,3,4,2,3,6,0,0,7,6,8,0,1,2,3,4],[4,5,6,7,4,3,2,3,4,1,0,3,0,1,1,2,3,4,2,3,6,0,0,7,6,8,0,1,2,3],[3,4,5,6,7,4,3,2,3,4,1,0,3,0,1,1,2,3,4,2,3,6,0,0,7,6,8,0,1,2],
[2,3,4,5,6,7,4,3,2,3,4,1,0,3,0,1,1,2,3,4,2,3,6,0,0,7,6,8,0,1],[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,4,3,2,3,4,1,0,3,0,1,1,2,3,4,2,3,6,0,0,7,6,8,0],
[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,4,3,2,3,4,1,0,3,0,1,1,2,3,4,2,3,6,0,0,7,6,8],[8,0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,4,3,2,3,4,1,0,3,0,1,1,2,3,4,2,3,6,0,0,7,6],
[6,8,0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,4,3,2,3,4,1,0,3,0,1,1,2,3,4,2,3,6,0,0,7],[7,6,8,0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,4,3,2,3,4,1,0,3,0,1,1,2,3,4,2,3,6,0,0],
[0,7,6,8,0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,4,3,2,3,4,1,0,3,0,1,1,2,3,4,2,3,6,0],[0,0,7,6,8,0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,4,3,2,3,4,1,0,3,0,1,1,2,3,4,2,3,6],
[6,0,0,7,6,8,0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,4,3,2,3,4,1,0,3,0,1,1,2,3,4,2,3],[3,6,0,0,7,6,8,0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,4,3,2,3,4,1,0,3,0,1,1,2,3,4,2],
     [2,3,6,0,0,7,6,8,0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,4,3,2,3,4,1,0,3,0,1,1,2,3,4],[4,2,3,6,0,0,7,6,8,0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,4,3,2,3,4,1,0,3,0,1,1,2,3],
     [3,4,2,3,6,0,0,7,6,8,0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,4,3,2,3,4,1,0,3,0,1,1,2],[2,3,4,2,3,6,0,0,7,6,8,0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,4,3,2,3,4,1,0,3,0,1,1]]

p2=Polyhedron(vertices = vert2)
p2
p2.Hrepresentation()
```

And here is the part of output:

```
 A 29-dimensional polyhedron in ZZ^30 defined as the convex hull of 30 vertices
(An equation (1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1) x - 91 == 0, An inequality (0, -6643755617445331037202609358, -1115451987061522518725310169, -4620824246361587837443723580, -3077838211630051976366550554, -2958690652672660811230373721, -974408181934402275593859480, -3250586099217454711737435326, -1999390120369594790625124513, -1415422103472822894852139772, -2534807215524130595973233650, -2780858391260346768723034201, -4072521014492760746645432088, -1331138469264064061646992630, -4722885096499104848736533209, -3180475210961898948969228316, -3851685143879995858104878858, -3228011163515660410829231425, -3072642994521821646580427696, -1374868705058151838371429430, -4889037447034222629220355689, -2510460065219895800789661380, -2297947035840486945050864530, -3657717103544642567050992273, -3458628241192993528820697768, -295584745844116667823309878, -3868958368255490017832885737, -6000440427999093271578675404, 853080186343081392188416198, -2835167870342318913892483281) x + 260907258623794816872847788563 >= 0, An inequality (0, -3688248056685400306080899479, -853080186343081392188416198, -7496835803788412429391025556, -1968532173404603910913726367, -5473904432704669229632139778, -3930918397973133368554966752, -3811770839015742203418789919, -1827488368277483667782275678, -4103666285560536103925851524, -2852470306712676182813540711, -2268502289815904287040555970, -3387887401867211988161649848, -3633938577603428160911450399, -4925601200835842138833848286, -2184218655607145453835408828, -5575965282842186240924949407, -4033555397304980341157644514, -4704765330223077250293295056, -4081091349858741803017647623, -3925723180864903038768843894, -2227948891401233230559845628, -5742117633377304021408771887, -3363540251562977192978077578, -3151027222183568337239280728, -4510797289887723959239408471, -4311708427536074921009113966, -1148664932187198060011726076, -4722038554598571410021301935, -6853520614342174663767091602) x + 338537555581015223561993662581 >= 0,
```

Comment: Note: also asked as [Ask Sage question 43613: Huge number in H-representation](https://ask.sagemath.org/question/43613).

Comment: I just have to ask, knowing relatively little about these things ... are you sure that this is actually wrong?